# Browser Scrollbar doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing an html page but the browser scrollbar doesn't appear when the content extends beyond the browser window. I'm a beginner at CSS and don't know exactly how to add attributes and how do they work. As you can see I've used W3.CSS and Bootstrap for the most part of design.
here's the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <title>Dr Salmani</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main class="centered dr-info">

    <div class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey">
      <div id="cases">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>شماره پرونده:</td>
            <td id="case_number">1080</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="fname" class="label">نام و نام خانوادگی:</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-input">
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" placeholder="نام و نام خانوادگی" readonly>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="pet_type" class="label">نوع حیوان:</label>
            </td>
            <td class="autocomplete">
              <div class="autocomplete">
                <input type="text" id="pet_type" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" name="pet_type" placeholder="نوع حیوان" readonly>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="age" class="label">سن:</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-input">
              <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="age" name="age" placeholder="سن" readonly>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="gender" class="label">جنس:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" placeholder="جنس" readonly>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="history" class="label">تاریخچه:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="history" name="history" placeholder="تاریخچه" readonly>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="case" class="label">شکایت اصلی:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="case" name="case" placeholder="شکایت اصلی" readonly>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey diagnose container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="diagnose">تشخیص:</label>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 400px;">
            <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="diagnse" name="diagnose" placeholder="تشخیص">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="treatment">درمان:</label>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 400px;">
            <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="treatment" name="treatment" placeholder="درمان">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey diagnose container">
      <table class="table w3-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">خدمات</th>
            <th scope="col">تعرفه</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">ویزیت</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="treatment" name="treatment" placeholder="درمان">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">جراحی</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="treatment" name="treatment" placeholder="درمان">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">تزریقات</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="treatment" name="treatment" placeholder="درمان">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">داروخانه</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="treatment" name="treatment" placeholder="درمان">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">رادیولوژی</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="treatment" name="treatment" placeholder="درمان">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">سونوگرافی</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="input w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" id="treatment" name="treatment" placeholder="درمان">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

and here's the CSS:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

tr,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.centered {
  position: fixed;
  /* or absolute */
  top: 20%;
  left: 13%;
}

.dr-info {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
}

main {
  width: 70%;
}

.td-input {
  width: 250px;
}

.diagnose {
  margin-top: 30px !important;
}
```

I've tried adding height and overflow attribute to body and html separately but it does nothing. Scrollbar appears to main tag when I add height and overflow attribute to it.
Opening the page with different browser doesn't make any change.

Comment: @Bravo I hope I understand what you mean but I don't mean the scrollbars in the snippet. I mean when I open the browser on my computer, scrollbar doesn't appear. And they've answered my question. So thank you for your time.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should've told that you should add the css to the html. Then the scrollbar doesn't show up. I'm so sorry to confuse you. @Bravo

Comment: Sorry I bothered you because I was new to this platform. By no means did I want to be rude or sth. I claim both answers fixed the issue Because they both said the same thing and I wanted to appreciate their time and investigation. @Bravo

Comment: pro tip: you can combine your css with your html code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main` container is positioned fixed and has a width of 70% - no matter the screen size. If you want to make this container scrollable, you should add the overflow property to this container, not body:

```
.dr-info {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your position is fixed in centered and dr-info class. Remove it scroll will start appearing.

```
.centered {
  /*position: fixed;*/
  /* or absolute */
  top: 20%;
  left: 13%;
}

.dr-info {
  /*position: fixed;*/
  top: 10%;
}
```